# android: No Launcher activity found

Tags: android

My AndroidManifest.xml is like the followings:

```
<application android:label="droid VNC server" android:icon="@drawable/icon"
android:name="MainApplication" android:debuggable="true">
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:launchMode="singleInstance"
    android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/icon">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                    <action android:name="org.onaips.vnc.ACTIVITY_UPDATE" />
    </intent-filter> 
</activity>
</application>
```

I already set the following two lines:

Why I still get the errors
No Launcher activity found
The launch will only sync the application package on the device

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the line

```
<action android:name="org.onaips.vnc.ACTIVITY_UPDATE" />
```

Because there are 2 similar lines, the 2nd line is usually considered. (Ambiguity). So just remove that line, and you will see the app in the launcher!

Answer (score 6):

Your `intent-filter` tag in xml file should exactly be like this:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Place it inside `<activity>` tag and you should be ok